# How can i show text from a textfile in a textblock? Xaml, BlankApp, Window8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I recently wanted to learn more about fileOpenPickers and decided to make a project. I made a FilOpenPicker. When i choose some textfile from the FileOpenPicker, I wanted to show it in the textblock. But i do not really know how to do that. Further i have a save button and a open button. When I press save it has to save the text from the OpenFilePicker somewhere on my computer. I writed some code, but it is not good at all.

Here is my code:

```
private async void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".log");
    StorageFile result = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (result != null)
    {
        try
        {
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(result, txtInhoud.Text);
            txtInhoud.Text = result.ToString(); 
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            txtInhoud.Text = result.ToString(); 
        }
    }

}

private async void  btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("MyFolder\\MyFile.txt",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    if (file != null)
    {
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "data");
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me out! I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Yes I will. The FileOpenPicker is good. It opens and I can pick up the textfile I have on my pc. What is not working is the way I want to put the data from the file to the textblock and how to save the data to my pc which is in the textbox after filling it. I hope you understand what I mean. And I hope you can helo me out!

Answer (score 0):

From the way you open the file picker, I assume you are targeting Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight?

In that case, the `FileIO.WriteTextAsync` method will not work since it's specific to the WinRT platform. Instead, use the [`StorageFile.OpenAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227221.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method and pass either `Read` or `ReadWrite` as access mode. Both versions will return a stream you can write to / read from.

For example, the code for saving the textbox' content could look as follows:

```
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
using (var writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)))
{
    writer.WriteString(txtInhoud.Text);
    await writer.StoreAsync();
    await writer.FlushAsync();
}
```

For more details (and an example of reading files), see [this blog post](http://tizianocacioppolini.blogspot.co.at/2014/01/windows-phone-8-folders-and-files.html) (sections *Write File* and *Read File*)!